# Python classes with decorated methods and __del__ defined do not get garbage collected: how do I uncouple the decorated method?

Tags: python, garbage-collection, decorator, python-decorators

I'm running into a problem with Python3.2. If a class decorates a function from the parent class and also has a destructor then instances of that class are never garbage collected.

Here's some sample code that illustrates the problem:

```
def super_simple_decorator(func):
    def f(*args, **kwds):
        return func(*args, **kwds)
    return f

class Parent():
    def foo(self):
        pass

class Child(Parent):
    def __del__(self):
        print('In Child.__del__')
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = super_simple_decorator(self.foo)

x = Child()
del x

import gc
_ = gc.collect()
print(gc.garbage)
```

If you are so inclined, you could also monkey-patch in a decorator at run-time and see the same thing:

```
class Garbage():
    def foo(self):
        pass
    def __del__(self):
        print('In Garbage.__del__')

g=Garbage()
g.foo = super_simple_decorator(g.foo)
del g
```

In each case, there is uncollected garbage, presumably because there is a bound reference to `self` in the decorated method.

Upgrading to Python3.4 isn't really an option for me at this point, so I'm looking for a way to let objects like these get garbage collected.

Comment: Does it help to wrap the `self.foo` reference in [weakref.ref](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html#weakref.ref)?

Comment: I thought about that, but then wouldn't it have to be called with `g.foo()()`?

Comment: Never-mind, I see the answer from @Martijn-Pieters now. I'll give those a try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not the decorator that causes this problem. It is the fact that you store a *method* on the instance they are bound to. The decorator is only the means here, not the actual cause.

Methods hold a reference to the instance in `__self__`, and you then created a circular reference by storing the method in a closure with the decorator object, back onto `self.foo`. *Don't do that*. Python 3.3 and before won't garbage collect circular references with objects with `__del__` methods.

Unwrap the method and store the original function:

```
self.foo = super_simple_decorator(self.foo.__func__)
```

`foo` will no longer be bound however, methods are only bound if looked up on the class, not the instance.

Or actually apply the decorator *at the class level*:

```
class Child(Parent):
    def __del__(self):
        print('In Child.__del__')
    foo = super_simple_decorator(Parent.foo)
```

If neither is an option, use a weak reference to track the instance, rather than reference the method, then rebind as needed:

```
import weakref

def super_simple_decorator(method):
    instance = weakref.ref(method.__self__)
    func = method.__func__
    def f(*args, **kwds):
        self = instance()  # can return None
        return func(self, *args, **kwds)
    return f
```

Comment: Applying the decorator at the class level isn't really an option for my less simplified scenario. The `__func__` option ends up with `TypeError: foo() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)` and the `weakref` options gives `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'self' referenced before assignment`.

Comment: The `weakref` issue with `UnboundLocalError` can be fixed by not re-using the name `self`.

Comment: @TrevorWiley yes, sorry about that, fixed now.